# Extracting Drivers from Disc

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, toshiba-laptop

Soooo.. I clean-installed windows 7 ultimate on my Toshiba Satellite A130-ST1311 (old, I know). And it came with a recovery disk to reinstall windows vista. It has all the drivers I need, but I don't want to install windows vista. (win vista came shipped with laptop).

Is there a way to extract the necessary drivers from that disk? Because some of the drivers are not anywhere on the Toshiba site (USB drivers to be specific). Plus the windows-provided drivers are no good.

Been searching around google for 3 days now, with no leads. Any form of help would be nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need 2 tools to this. [7ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/) and [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) (or other software that does the same)

Start 7zip and navigate to your vista dvd and browse to sources folder and double click install.wim

[image]

Open install.win you will see 13 folders ,open folder 1 ,DO NOT extract all of the folders in install.wim you will only fill up your hard drive.

[image]

Head to Folder called Windows

[image]

Then in the System32 browse for folders called Drivers and Drivestore

[image]

Extract only those folders. You will to need to rename all the files in folder en-US, renaming all these files one by one will take a long time so we need a application to bulk rename these.

Using Bulk Rename Utility browse to `...\driverstore\en-US`

Do notice that every file ends in .inf_loc you need to rename these to .inf

[image]

press ctrl and A to selcet all , then in the extension box select fixed and enter .inf ,hit the rename button and your done!

Now you can head to your device manager and update all the necessary drivers by simply choosing I have a disk option and browsing to the extracted Drivers.

[SOURCE CREDIT](http://forum.raymond.cc/threads/how-to-extract-drivers-from-vista-dvd-for-windows-7.15176/)

Comment: The content of this answer appears to have been **copied** from http://forum.raymond.cc/threads/how-to-extract-drivers-from-vista-dvd-for-windows-7.15176/ -- some credit would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Toshiba site has "process" to update a vista machine to a win 7.

[Toshiba update process](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/bulletin.jsp?soid=2450599)

This states that it requires your serial #, in particular the second character and build date to guide you and the laptop to the proper method of update/upgrade and secure proper drivers.

Comment: Sorry. My laptop was made in 2006. Satellite A130-ST1311

Comment: Link to Toshiba update process now fails.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Bulk Rename Utility as suggested by Darius above, instead either

go to the en-US folder in Explorer and right-click to open Command Prompt from the Context menu
or
open a Command Prompt window and then move to the en-US folder

and, either way, use the command `ren *.inf_loc *.inf`